# Pass 2D array to function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I am new to programming.

User will be enter the size of 2D array and then I want to pass this array to function. How can I do this?

Comment: Can't do it like that. Variable length arrays aren't a feature of C++. Try `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for a start.

Comment: Can't i do this even using pointer?

Comment: You could. But you'll probably spent a few hours debugging all the illegal memory access your program will have. `std::vector` was designed so you or I won't have to do these things by hand with pointers.

Comment: Not duplicate.. In my question size of array is not constant like array[10][10] in your mentioned question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish your goal.

The *first way* is using dynamically allocated C-style arrays. You shouldn't do this in C++ unless you are forced to support existing code. But in this case it is better to consider refactoring, maybe.

The *second way* is using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). This class encapsulates low-level manipulations with memory. It will free you from many potential bugs.

To show you advantages of `std::vector` I have written two programs. They input sizes of 2D array (in another way, it is called a matrix) and create it.

Creating matrix using C-style arrays requests a lot of code and manipulations with pointers. **For the sake of simplicity the following code doesn't handle exceptions.** In real code you should do it to avoid memory leaks, but the code would become even harder.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

void function(int** matrix, size_t nrows, size_t ncols)
{

}

int main()
{
    size_t nrows;
    size_t ncols;

    cin >> nrows >> ncols;

    // allocate memory for matrix
    int** matrix = new int*[nrows];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
        matrix[i] = new int[ncols];

    function(matrix, nrows, ncols);

    // release memory
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
        delete[] matrix[i];
    delete[] matrix;
}
```

So in C++ it would be very easier using `std::vector`. Since `std::vector` is a class it has constructor and destructor encapsulating allocating and releasing memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void function(vector<vector<int>>& matrix)
{

}

int main()
{
    size_t nrows;
    size_t ncols;

    cin >> nrows >> ncols;

    // create matrix
    vector<vector<int>> matrix(nrows);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
        matrix[i] = vector<int>(ncols);

    // you don't even need to pass sizes of matrix
    function(matrix);

    // automatically called destructor of matrix releases memory
}
```